# Load dropdown item but disable for selection

Tags: dom

So I want to be able to load the 'Choose' dropdown option, but disable it as soon as a change is made on the drop-down.

I've attempted adding a `disabled` attribute tag on the selection, but it loads on 'Alabama' and I don't want that.

How would I be able to tackle this?

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So on selecting of alabama it should be disabled and what should be the selected value Choose.. ? Also once you select on alabama should it been shown in the options list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `hidden` and `selected` to the first option should do the trick.

```html
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="resident" required>
            <option hidden selected value="">Choose...</option>
            <option>Alabama</option>
            <option>Alaska</option>
            <option>Colorado</option>
            <option>New York</option>
            <option>South Dakota</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select state of residence.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to still see the "Choose..." after the user has made a selection, replace `hidden` with `disabled`.

Comment: It's nice this doesn't rely on javascript to function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable the first option? (no javascript is needed and the result is like what you want to achieve I think):

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="resident" required>
            <option value="" disabled>Choose...</option>
            <?php foreach (Vars::states() as $abbr => $state): ?>
                <option value="<?= $abbr; ?>"><?= $state; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select state of residence.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a demo code snippet of what it looks like:

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">Alabama</option>
    <option value="2">Alaska</option>
    <option value="3">...</option>
</select>
```